# Android custom progress bar like the animation of moving train in Capitaine Train application

Tags: android, animation, user-interface, graphics

Can anyone point to a code snippet or point me to right resources for achieving this functionality.

[image]

I want to achieve the moving train animation functionality which shows above the progress bar. This shows image moving forward as the progression is loading.

Comment: @dsum27, next time, for us [reviewers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5333937), please mention that you are moving the OP's comment into the question.

Comment: You can have a look at an article I wrote to describe how this is done: https://plus.google.com/118417777153109946393/posts/hZcCzmNBFzG

Comment: I did that Cyril, got it working, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I have to assume you are asking about the progess bar.

There is plenty of docs about progressionbar. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) the documentation.

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

 private ProgressBar mProgress;
 private int mProgressStatus = 0;

 private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.progressbar_activity);

     mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

     // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                 mProgressStatus = doWork();

                 // Update the progress bar
                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     }).start();
 }
 }
```

[Here](http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/) is some good information about customizing. Build your custom progress bar styles here.

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:progress="50"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar2" />
```

You can customize it more by building shape objects in xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
  <shape>
  <corners android:radius="5dip" />
  <gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
    android:centerY="0.5"
    android:endColor="#ff747674"
    android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d" />
</shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
<clip>
  <shape>
    <corners android:radius="5dip" />
      <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#ff009900"
        android:startColor="#ff000099" />
  </shape>
</clip>
```

Edit:

If you are looking to load an animated image into view you can use this [code](https://code.google.com/p/apidemos/source/browse/trunk/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapDecode.java#103). Which is in the Apidemos on the emulator. Go check it out first and see how it works.

```
package com.example.android.apis.graphics;

import com.example.android.apis.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class BitmapDecode extends GraphicsActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SampleView(this));
}

private static class SampleView extends View {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Bitmap mBitmap2;
    private Bitmap mBitmap3;
    private Bitmap mBitmap4;
    private Drawable mDrawable;

    private Movie mMovie;
    private long mMovieStart;

    private static byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream is) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        }
        return os.toByteArray();
    }

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.beach);

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bm;

        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);

        // now opts.outWidth and opts.outHeight are the dimension of the
        // bitmap, even though bm is null

        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;    // this will request the bm
        opts.inSampleSize = 4;             // scaled down by 4
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);

        mBitmap = bm;

        // decode an image with transparency
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.frog);
        mBitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        // create a deep copy of it using getPixels() into different configs
        int w = mBitmap2.getWidth();
        int h = mBitmap2.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[w*h];
        mBitmap2.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
        mBitmap3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, 0, w, w, h,
                                       Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmap4 = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, 0, w, w, h,
                                       Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        mDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button);
        mDrawable.setBounds(150, 20, 300, 100);

        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.animated_gif);
        if (true) {
            mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
        } else {
            byte[] array = streamToBytes(is);
            mMovie = Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
        }
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC);            

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 10, 10, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap2, 10, 170, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap3, 110, 170, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap4, 210, 170, null);

        mDrawable.draw(canvas);

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }
        if (mMovie != null) {
            int dur = mMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 1000;
            }
            int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
            mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - mMovie.width(),
                        getHeight() - mMovie.height());
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually, I am concerned about achieving the moving train animation above the progress bar, while the search results loads in background.

Comment: I see. That is a little hard to get from your question. I will update my answer. Would you please also update your question so it benefits other users.